# how to use curdate() in where clause against unixtimestamp (bigint) column

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I am trying to pull records in the past 7 days. This is my select statement that I have been trying to get to work:

```
select from_unixtime(time,'%m/%d/%y') as fdate, from_unixtime(time,'%h:%m:%s') as ftime
from mdl_log
where from_unixtime(time,'%y-%m-%d')  between curdate() and curdate() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

I have tried various incarnations of the where clause like

```
where time between curdate() and curdate() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

and

```
where from_unixtime(time,'%yyyy-%mm-%dd')  between curdate() and curdate() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

and

```
where date(time) between curdate() and curdate() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

select curdate() - results in the date showing in this format 2012-11-08

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there with your last incarnation. However, you need to compare apples to apples. Since `time` is an *integer*, you need to convert it for [MySQL date/time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions) to use.

```
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) between CURDATE() and CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Given your use case, you really only need [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime):

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(time) between CURDATE() and CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: hmmm, thanks for response.  I am getting an empty result set using either of the about suggestions.  I tried adding FROM_UNIXTIME(time,'%yyyy-%mm-%dd') too.

Comment: I ended up using this statement where DATE(from_unixtime(time,'%Y-%m-%d')  )> DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)

Comment: That is unnecessary. I think you're still missing the point. Both of the examples I provided should work given that `time` is a `BIGINT`.