# MYSQL Convert timestamp to Month

Tags: mysql

I have this certain problem about mysql date functions.

I'm trying to compare the value of THIS MONTH to the given timestamp in database.

For example, month today is june, and the timestamp is **1369967316**

And I'm trying to determine if that timestamp is in month of june.

```
$query = db_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(CURDATE())) = MONTH(1369967316)");

//count total members this mont
$members_month = $query->rowCount();
```

so if I used the rowCount, the $members_month should have the value of 1.

Unfortunately it doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Well I saw some answers that some kind of relevant to mine but it doesn't hit the spot or I didn't applied it well.

[mysql get month from timestamp not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085629/mysql-get-month-from-timestamp-not-working)

[how to use curdate() in where clause against unixtimestamp (bigint) column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293570/how-to-use-curdate-in-where-clause-against-unixtimestamp-bigint-column)

Comment: Did you try `MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(1369967316))`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I also did that, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```
mysql> SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(1369967316));
+----------------------------------+
| MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(1369967316)) |
+----------------------------------+
|                                5 |
+----------------------------------+
```

Your issue is likely coming from the fact that 1369967316 is May 30th, not June (as you expect), thus resulting in an inequality with `MONTH(CURDATE())`.

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1369967316);
+---------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(1369967316) |
+---------------------------+
| 2013-05-30 22:28:36       |
+---------------------------+
```