# How to get month from timestamp value?

Tags: mysql

There is table called `payment` and `timestamp` is column which has data like `1462399200`.I want to extract records of specific month from this database table. For example I want all records of May month.Here is the code I am using, but it isn't yielding me any result.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM payment WHERE monthname(timestamp)=5";
```

`$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);`

```
$counta=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(1462399200)), Please try this and let me know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract the Day / Month / Year from a Timestamp on MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900743/extract-the-day-month-year-from-a-timestamp-on-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

You could use this

```
SELECT *
FROM payment 
WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = MONTH(CURDATE())
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = YEAR(CURDATE());
```

To get all values for this month.

```
SELECT *
FROM payment 
WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = 1
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = 2016;
```

And the second option to get all values for january 2016

Please let me know if this is helpfull.

Comment: then please select it as the answer so that the question can be closed

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below code:-

```
 mysql> SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(1462399200));
```

[MYSQL Convert timestamp to Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035854/mysql-convert-timestamp-to-month)

I have also mentioned in comment

Comment: You can also use MONTHNAME() function here